# Configure an IPSEC VPN connexion with OpenBSD (host to gateway)

Tags: vpn, openbsd

I'm trying to configure an IPsec VPN connexion with OpenBSD as a VPN Server with 3-DES  for the Encryption, HMAC-SHA-1 for the Integrity, and PresharedKey for the Authentification.

My Questions are :

- If it's possible to do it with OpenBSD, can anybody give me a working tutorial to do this?
- If it's not possible to do it with OpenBSD, can anybody give me others solution and tutorials for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found in the past [these guides](http://www.kernel-panic.it/openbsd/vpn/index.html) very useful.
if you want to use l2tp/ipsec with npppd check out [this undeadly article](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20120427125048).
finally if you plan to use openvpn we have assembled a small guide [at our site](http://www.2f30.org/guides/openvpn.html).